# Explain what is happening with ternary operator in Ruby method

Tags: ruby

I have a method that is working for my purposes, the only thing is that I really don't know what is going on and could use an explaination in laymans terms. Specifically the last evaluated line:

```
hash.map{ |k,v| v==max[1] ? k : nil }.compact.sort_by(&:length).first
```

This is my code:

```
 def self.largest_hash_key(hash)
    max = hash.max_by{ |k,v| v }
    seven = hash.max_by{ |k,v| k.length }.first
    if seven.length == 7
     seven
    else
     hash.map{ |k,v| v==max[1] ? k : nil }.compact.sort_by(&:length).first
    end
  end
```

Comment: what's your input and expected output? we may give you better solutions.

Comment: The use of `seven` as a variable name makes me gag. As does the method name `largest_hash_key` if it returns anything other than the largest hash key, all the time.

Comment: At least it's not set somewhere as a constant like `SEVEN = 49`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns a projection based on the value(s) passed in.  In this case it is returning an array made up of - for each key/value pair - the hash key or `nil`, depending on whether the value matches `max[1]`.

```
[1, 2, 3].map{|a| a.odd? ? a : nil}
=> [1, nil, 3]
```

In this case, the `hash` is converted to just the keys where the values match `max[1]` (nils are stripped out by `compact`), then sorted by their length, and the first (smallest length) is returned.

This algorithm can use quite a bit of improvement, but that's how the line in question works.

Answer (score 1):

```
 hash.map{ |k,v| v==max[1] ? k : nil }.compact.sort_by(&:length).first
```

Means:

```
For the hash passed in
For each key-value pair (that's the `.map`)
See if the value matches the maxiumum value that was found in the hash 
    by the `hash.max_by{ |k,v| v }` expression

If so, use the that key value, otherwise use nil (ignore it)
Take that result and `compact` it make it be the actual result (remove those nil elements).
Sort by length # Not sure if this is needed?
Return the key-value pair as an array rather than the hash passed in.
```